# Some styling applies while others not, and I don't understand why

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am building a portfolio website and most of it is done.
However, I've noticed some strange things with Tailwind CSS. I've applied styling and for the most part it works, but some stylings don't apply. Some apply at certain break points but disappear at other break points, even though I haven't found a rule that says it should.

Typically this happens mostly with overflow effects, hover and list-styles.

I've included the components managing the work experience section of my site.
Here is the parent component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
import ExperienceCard from './ExperienceCard'
import { Experience } from '../typings'

type Props = {
  experiences: Experience[]
}

const WorkExperience = ({ experiences }: Props) => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 1.5 }}
      className='h-screen flex relative overflow-hidden flex-col text-left
      md:flex-row max-w-full px-10 justify-evenly mx-auto items-center'
    >

      <h3 className='absolute top-24 uppercase tracking-[20px] text-gray-500 text-2xl'>
        Experience
      </h3>

      <div className='w-full flex space-x-5 overflow-x-scroll p-10 snap-x snap-mandatory
      scrollbar scrollbar-track-gray-400/20 scrollbar-thumb-[#F7AB0A]'>
        {experiences?.map((exp) => (
          <ExperienceCard key={exp._id} experience={exp} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  )
}

export default WorkExperience
```

Code for the child component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
import { Experience } from '../typings'
import { urlFor } from '../sanity'

type Props = {
  experience: Experience
}

const ExperienceCard = ({ experience }: Props) => {
  console.log(experience);

  return (
    <article
      className='flex flex-col rounded-lg items-center space-y-7 flex-shrink-0
       w-[500px] h-[500px] md:w-[600px] md:h-[600px] xl:w-[900px] snap-center p-10 bg-[#292929] hover:opacity-100
       opacity-40 cursor-pointer transition-opacity duration-200 overflow-hidden'
    >
      <motion.img
        initial={{
          y: -100,
          opacity: 0,
        }}
        whileInView={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 1.2 }}
        viewport={{ once: true }}
        src={urlFor(experience?.companyImage).url()}
        alt='logo'
        className='h-32 w-32 rounded-full xl:w-[200px] xl:h-[200px] object-cover object-center'
      />

      <div className='px-0 md:px-10'>
        <h4 className='text-4xl font-light'>{experience?.jobTitle}</h4>
        <p className='font-bold text-2xl mt-1'>{experience?.company}</p>

        <div className='flex space-x-2 my-2'>
          {experience?.technologies.map((tech) => (
            <img
              key={tech._id}
              src={urlFor(tech?.image).url()}
              alt='techStack'
              className='rounded-full h-10 w-10' />
          ))}
        </div>

        <p className='uppercase py-5 text-gray-300'>
          {new Date(experience.dateStarted).toDateString()}
          &nbsp; &#8212; &nbsp; {experience.isCurrentlyWorkingHere
            ? 'Present'
            : new Date(experience.dateEnded).toDateString()}
        </p>

        <ul className='list-disc space-y-4 ml-5 text-lg overflow-scroll pr-5 scrollbar-thin scrollbar-track-black scrollbar-thumb-[#F7AB0A]/80 max-h-96'>
          {experience?.points.map((point, i) => (
            <li key={i}>{point}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </article>
  )
}

export default ExperienceCard
```

Tailwind configs:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('tailwind-scrollbar')
  ],
}
```

Postcss configs:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

globals.css file:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .heroButton {
    @apply px-6 py-2 border border-[#242424] rounded-full uppercase text-xs tracking-widest text-gray-500 transition-all hover:border-[#F7AB0A]/40 hover:text-[#F7AB0A]/40
  }

  .contactInput {
    @apply outline-none bg-slate-400/10 rounded-sm border-b px-6 py-4 border-[#242424]
    text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 transition-all focus:border-[#F7AB0A]/40
    focus:text-[#F7AB0A]/40 hover:border-[#F7AB0A]/40
  }
}
```

When I do hover over the applied class styling with Tailwind, it does appear like it should, to show it's been recognized.
I'm at a loss, why it works sometimes but then it stops and some things just never work...

I've tried changing the class styling order, different values to see if things happen. Not much.
Also inspected through browser if the styling is there. I can see it's there on the element but visually it's not applied?

I've used Firefox and Chromium in this case.

Comment: i see heroButton and contactInput in your css but i dont see them in your jsx? or did i miss them?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me

I solved this problem by adding a new script to the `package.json` file

the "`dev`" script:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build src/input.css -o dist/output.css",
    "dev": "npx tailwindcss -i src/input.css -o dist/output.css --watch"
  }
```

and run it:

```bash
npm run dev
```

this will watch the changes in your HTML and compile CSS accordingly.